# AWS CDK user pool authorizer

Tags: javascript, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I'm trying to create an API gateway using the AWS-CDK and protect the REST endpoints with a Cognito user pool authorizer.

I cannot find any examples how one would do this.   I thought it should look something like this but maybe the methods I need do not exist?

```
const cdk       = require('@aws-cdk/cdk');
const lambda    = require('@aws-cdk/aws-lambda');
const apigw     = require('@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway');

const path  = require('path');

// 
// Define the stack:
class MyStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor (parent, id, props) {
        super(parent, id, props);    

        var tmethodHandler = new lambda.Function(this, 'test-lambda', {
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.NodeJS810,
            handler: 'index.handler',
            code: lambda.Code.directory( path.join( __dirname, 'lambda')),
        });

        var api         = new apigw.RestApi(this, 'test-api');

        const tmethod   = api.root.addResource('testmethod');

        const tmethodIntegration    = new apigw.LambdaIntegration(tmethodHandler);

        tmethod.addMethod('GET', getSessionIntegration, {
            authorizationType: apigw.AuthorizationType.Cognito,
            authorizerId : 'crap!!!?'
        });

    }
}

class MyApp extends cdk.App {
    constructor (argv) {
        super(argv);

        new MyStack(this, 'test-apigw');
    }
}

console.log(new MyApp(process.argv).run());
```

Comment: I realize that Authorizers may be a missing feature, https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/issues/723 , however it's not apparent to me how to work around it with the @aws-cdk/api-gateway.cloudformation features either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what looks like a mechanism... I was able to get it to work like this:

```js
var auth = new apigw.cloudformation.AuthorizerResource(this, 'myAuthorizer', {
    restApiId: api.restApiId,
    authorizerName: 'mypoolauth',
    authorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 300,
    identitySource: 'method.request.header.Authorization',
    providerArns: [ 'arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-west-2:redacted:userpool/redacted' ],
    type: "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
});

tmethod.addMethod('GET', getSessionIntegration, {
    authorizationType: apigw.AuthorizationType.Cognito,
    authorizerId : auth.authorizerId
});
```

Now to figure out how to enable CORS headers on API Gateway...

Answer (score 23):

As of `September 2019` @bgdnip answer doesnt translate exactly for `typescript`. I got it working with the following:

```
const api = new RestApi(this, 'RestAPI', {
    restApiName: 'Rest-Name',
    description: 'API for journey services.',
});

const putIntegration = new LambdaIntegration(handler);

const auth = new CfnAuthorizer(this, 'APIGatewayAuthorizer', {
    name: 'customer-authorizer',
    identitySource: 'method.request.header.Authorization',
    providerArns: [providerArn.valueAsString],
    restApiId: api.restApiId,
    type: AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
});

const post = api.root.addMethod('PUT', putIntegration, { authorizationType: AuthorizationType.COGNITO });
const postMethod = post.node.defaultChild as CfnMethod;
postMethod.addOverride('Properties.AuthorizerId', { Ref: auth.logicalId });
```

This is from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_resource_props

**UPDATE October**

The above is already out of date and unnecessary and can be achieved with the following with `aws-cdk 1.12.0`

```
const api = new RestApi(this, 'RestAPI', {
    restApiName: 'Rest-Name',
    description: 'API for journey services.',
});

const putIntegration = new LambdaIntegration(handler);

const auth = new CfnAuthorizer(this, 'APIGatewayAuthorizer', {
    name: 'customer-authorizer',
    identitySource: 'method.request.header.Authorization',
    providerArns: [providerArn.valueAsString],
    restApiId: api.restApiId,
    type: AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
});

const post = api.root.addMethod('PUT', putIntegration, {
    authorizationType: AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
    authorizer: { authorizerId: auth.ref }
});
```

Comment: what is `providerArn`?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/authorizer/ See here.

Comment: Thanks, I get what it means, but I'm wondering, how the `providerArn` object is created

Comment: `providerArn.valueAsString` returns an error `'valueAsString' does not exist on type 'IResolvable'`.  One must use `.toString()` for an iResolvable.

Comment: @PaulS that particular example is using `providerArn` from `CfnParameter` - dont believe that has changed? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.CfnParameter.html

Comment: Just trying to be helpful for different scenario.  Don't get me started on CDK naming conventions, which is wildly inconsistent with itself and CFT... (and really besides docs the only really negative part of CDK which is otherwise what I've been looking for for years in terms of cloud as code)

Answer (score 5):

The previous answers no longer work because the `authorizerId` property was replaced with `authorizer`, which isn't fully implemented at this time.

Instead, it can be done by using the underlying CfnResource objects, [as described in the official guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html).

Here's Python code as an example:

```py
from aws_cdk import cdk
from aws_cdk import aws_apigateway


class Stk(cdk.Stack):
    def __init__(self, app, id):
        super().__init__(app, id)

        api_gw = aws_apigateway.RestApi(self, 'MyApp')
        post_method = api_gw.root.add_method(http_method='POST')

        # Create authorizer using low level CfnResource
        api_gw_authorizer = aws_apigateway.CfnAuthorizer(
            scope=self,
            id='my_authorizer',
            rest_api_id=api_gw.rest_api_id,
            name='MyAuth',
            type='COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
            identity_source='method.request.header.name.Authorization',
            provider_arns=[
                'arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:123456789012:userpool/'
                'eu-west-1_MyCognito'])

        # Get underlying post_method Resource object. Returns CfnMethod
        post_method_resource = post_method.node.find_child('Resource')
        # Add properties to low level resource
        post_method_resource.add_property_override('AuthorizationType',
                                                   'COGNITO_USER_POOLS')
        # AuthorizedId uses Ref, simulate with a dictionaty
        post_method_resource.add_property_override(
                'AuthorizerId',
                {"Ref": api_gw_authorizer.logical_id})


app = cdk.App()
stk = Stk(app, "myStack")

app.synth()
```

Comment: Python approach looks great this way. The way Python separate resources and constructs (ie: Cfn classes prefixes) is really different. You might look at some NodeJS solutions and not right away identify we need to go down to the Resource level (Cfn) to set CfnMethod authorizer id

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution in TypeScript (based somewhat on bgdnlp's response)

```
import { App, Stack, Aws } from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { Code, Function, Runtime } from '@aws-cdk/aws-lambda';
import { LambdaIntegration, RestApi, CfnAuthorizer, CfnMethod } from '@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway';

const app = new App();
const stack = new Stack(app, `mystack`);
const api = new RestApi(stack, `myapi`);

const region = Aws.REGION;
const account = Aws.ACCOUNT_ID;
const cognitoArn = `arn:aws:cognito-idp:${region}:${account}:userpool/${USER_POOL_ID}`;

const authorizer = new CfnAuthorizer(stack, 'Authorizer', {
  name: `myauthorizer`,
  restApiId: api.restApiId,
  type: 'COGNITO_USER_POOLS',
  identitySource: 'method.request.header.Authorization',
  providerArns: [cognitoArn],
});

const lambda = new Function(stack, 'mylambda', {
  runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
  code: Code.asset('dist'),
  handler: `index.handler`,
});

const integration = new LambdaIntegration(lambda);

const res = api.root.addResource('hello');

const method = res.addMethod('GET', integration);

const child = method.node.findChild('Resource') as CfnMethod;

child.addPropertyOverride('AuthorizationType', 'COGNITO_USER_POOLS');

child.addPropertyOverride('AuthorizerId', { Ref: authorizer.logicalId });
```

Answer (score 4):

Indeed. there is no example to do this via copy and paste ;). here is my example to create AWS cognito user pool and connect user pol authorizer with API gateway and lambda function using AWS CDK based on Java with Version 0.24.1.

This example ist just an example to provide an protected API for function called "Foo".

- Cognito User Pool
- API Gateway
- Lambda
- DynamoDB

  ```
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Cognito User Pool
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  CfnUserPool userPool = new CfnUserPool(this, "cognito",
      CfnUserPoolProps.builder()
          .withAdminCreateUserConfig(
              AdminCreateUserConfigProperty.builder()
                  .withAllowAdminCreateUserOnly(false)
                  .build())
          .withPolicies(
              PoliciesProperty.builder()
                  .withPasswordPolicy(
                      PasswordPolicyProperty.builder()
                          .withMinimumLength(6)
                          .withRequireLowercase(false)
                          .withRequireNumbers(false)
                          .withRequireSymbols(false)
                          .withRequireUppercase(false)
                          .build()
                  )
                  .build()
          )
          .withAutoVerifiedAttributes(Arrays.asList("email"))
          .withSchema(Arrays.asList(
              CfnUserPool.SchemaAttributeProperty.builder()
                  .withAttributeDataType("String")
                  .withName("email")
                  .withRequired(true)
                  .build()))
          .build());

  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Cognito User Pool Client
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  new CfnUserPoolClient(this, "cognitoClient",
      CfnUserPoolClientProps.builder()
          .withClientName("UserPool")
          .withExplicitAuthFlows(Arrays.asList("ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH"))
          .withRefreshTokenValidity(90)
          .withUserPoolId(userPool.getRef())
          .build());

  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Lambda function
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Function function = new Function(this, "function.foo",
      FunctionProps.builder()
          // lamda code located in /functions/foo
          .withCode(Code.asset("functions/foo"))
          .withHandler("index.handler")
          .withRuntime(Runtime.NODE_J_S810)
          .build());

  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  // DynamoDB Table
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Table table = new Table(this, "dynamodb.foo", TableProps.builder()
      .withTableName("foo")
      .withPartitionKey(Attribute.builder()
          .withName("id")
          .withType(AttributeType.String)
          .build())
      .build());

  // GRANTS function -> table
  table.grantReadWriteData(function.getRole());

  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  // API Gateway
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------

  // API Gateway REST API with lambda integration
  LambdaIntegration lambdaIntegration = new LambdaIntegration(function);
  RestApi restApi = new RestApi(this, "foo");

  // Authorizer configured with cognito user pool
  CfnAuthorizer authorizer = new CfnAuthorizer(this, "authorizer",
      CfnAuthorizerProps.builder()
          .withName("cognitoAuthorizer")
          .withRestApiId(restApi.getRestApiId())
          .withIdentitySource("method.request.header.Authorization")
          .withProviderArns(Arrays.asList(userPool.getUserPoolArn()))
          .withType("COGNITO_USER_POOLS")
          .build());

  // Bind authorizer to API ressource
  restApi.getRoot().addMethod("ANY", lambdaIntegration, MethodOptions
      .builder()
        .withAuthorizationType(AuthorizationType.Cognito)
        .withAuthorizerId(authorizer.getAuthorizerId())
      .build());
  ```

Answer (score 4):

You have to:

- create the api gateway
- set Cognito as authorizer in the api gateway
- set the authorization in your method
- set your integration with the lambda to 'Use Lambda Proxy integration'. The LambdaIntegration properties has on true this value by default, so don't worry for it

Finally, make a request adding the token in the Header. The API gateway will validate it with Cognito. If this pass then, your lambda will be triggered and in the event you can find the claims ***event.requestContext.authorizer.claims***.

```js
const lambda = require("@aws-cdk/aws-lambda");
const apiGateway = require('@aws-cdk/aws-apigateway'); 

 const api = new apiGateway.RestApi(
      this,
      '<id-ApiGateway>',
      {
        restApiName: '<ApiGateway-name>',
      },
    );

    const auth = new apiGateway.CfnAuthorizer(this, '<id>', {
      name: "<authorizer-name>",
      type: apiGateway.AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
      authorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 300,
      identitySource: "method.request.header.Authorization",
      restApiId: api.restApiId,
      providerArns: ['<userPool.userPoolArn>'],
    });

    const myLambda= new lambda.Function(this, "<id>", {
      functionName: '<lambda-name>',
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
      handler: "<your-handler>",
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("<path>"), // TODO: modify the way to get the path
    });

      const lambdaIntegration = new apiGateway.LambdaIntegration(myLambda);

      const resource = api.root.resourceForPath('<your-api-path>');
      // When the API will be deployed, the URL will look like this
      // https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/<your-api-path>

      const authorizationOptions = {
        apiKeyRequired: false,
        authorizer: {authorizerId: auth.ref},
        authorizationType: 'COGNITO_USER_POOLS'
      };

      resource.addMethod(
        GET, // your method
        lambdaIntegration,
        authorizationOptions
      );
```

Comment: AWS CDK,  API gateway integration with Lambda and using Cognito user pool as Authorizer

Comment: Ready, added an explanation

Answer (score 2):

For the weirdos using the Java version of the CDK (like me), you can utilize the setters on the Cfn constructs:

```java
final UserPool userPool = ...
final RestApi restApi = ...
final LambdaIntegration integration = ...
final Method method = restApi.getRoot().addMethod("GET", integration);

final CfnAuthorizer cognitoAuthorizer = new CfnAuthorizer(this, "CfnCognitoAuthorizer",
        CfnAuthorizerProps.builder()
                .name("CognitoAuthorizer")
                .restApiId(restApi.getRestApiId())
                .type("COGNITO_USER_POOLS")
                .providerArns(Arrays.asList(userPool.getUserPoolArn()))
                .identitySource("method.request.header.Authorization")
                .build());

final CfnMethod cfnMethod = (CfnMethod) method.getNode().getDefaultChild();
cfnMethod.setAuthorizationType("COGNITO_USER_POOLS");
cfnMethod.setAuthorizerId(cognitoAuthorizer.getRef());
```

Answer (score 1):

As of v1.88 this is now supported directly in CDK

```
const userPool = new cognito.UserPool(this, 'UserPool');

const auth = new apigateway.CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer(this, 'booksAuthorizer', {
  cognitoUserPools: [userPool]
});

declare const books: apigateway.Resource;
books.addMethod('GET', new apigateway.HttpIntegration('http://amazon.com'), {
  authorizer: auth,
  authorizationType: apigateway.AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
});
```

[AWS CDK API V1 Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer.html)

[AWS CDK API V2 Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer.html)

Comment: this is the most clever and correct response. Just face palms seeing other answers above . thanks

Comment: nice that you have provided reference for V1 and V2, cause looking again at the responses above, people have no idea about V2 it seems )))

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently using **CDK v2** or **CDK v1(latest)**. This has been made easy:

```
// Your cognito userpool
const userPool = new cognito.UserPool(this, "MyUserPool")

// Authorizer for your userpool
const cognitoAuthorizer = new apigw.CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer(
  this,
  "CognitoAuthorierOnLambda",
  {
    cognitoUserPools: [userPool],
  }
);

// Rest Api
const api = new apigw.RestApi(this, 'myApi', {
  defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
    allowOrigins: apigw.Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
    allowMethods: apigw.Cors.ALL_METHODS, // this is also the default
  },
  deploy: true
});

// add /getItems endpoint
const getItems = api.root.addResource('getItems');

// attach lambda to this endpoint 
const getItemsIntegration = new apigw.LambdaIntegration(getItemsLambdaFunction);    

// make the endpoint secure with cognito userpool           
getItems.addMethod('GET', getAllItemsIntegration, {
  authorizer:cognitoAuthorizer
});
```